# angular2 rc6 quickstart , typescript configuration differences with rc5

Tags: angular, typescript

Why in angular2 rc6 quickstart don't exclude folder node_modules from compilation like angular2 rc5 quickstart?

see exclude section ; angular2 rc5 quickstart, tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

angular2 rc6 quickstart, no exclude section, tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

when i do , npm start, tsc compile all files include node_modules; that is ok ? js files are rewritten?  some node modules are pure typescript and they need be compiled? why  quickstart configuration for typescript is different with rc5 and rc6?

Comment: I kept my "exclude" configuration when moved to RC6. Seems to work just fine. Actually, I don't think I've made any changes to tsconfig at all.

Comment: @rook but i've read now angular2 have packages in typescript; so maybe it's needed to compile;  the problem is new version type script 2. give problems...

Comment: What problems? As I said, I didn't make any changes to tsconfig moving RC4->RC5->RC6 and I'm not noticing any issues.

Comment: i'm not sure; because im not expert , but you keep your old folder node_modules when you do upgrade, i dont' know if it's work if you delete node_modules and do: npm install